# Using 3rd Party DNS provider to point subdomain to EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, subdomain

Having a issue with pointing a subdomain to my EC2 image server. Currently our DNS provider is UltraDNS my webservers are on physical boxes with another hosting company for some reason the last person working on this site migrated all the site images to an EC2 instance.

I created an A record with xxx.domain.com pointing to the EC2's elastic ip in UltraDNS but the instance is inaccessible still even with 30 TTL. Am I missing a step?

Comment: If you go to https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/ and enter `xxx.domain.com`, do you get the correct IP address?

Comment: @DusanBajic it does show the correct ip DNS is now resolving but I'm getting a 404 when i hit the subdomain.

Comment: Than this is not DNS issue, but probably webserver config issue.